# Fraud: Is there any way to block a specific postal code (address)?

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, validation, address, fraud

we've been receiving quite a lot of fraudulent transactions and they're all being delivered to the same address, I was wondering if there was any way I could block customers from using a specific post code or address?

We're actively blocking ip addresses but they're changing so frequently

TIA

Answer (score 0):

You could set up an observer that would check order's or shipping's postal code and if it's in the list of predefined postal codes then stop the order creation and throw an exception.

One of the events to which you can hook your observer into would be `sales_order_place_before`.

You could also set this up on customer creation/update but this would require duplicating code for customer registration and update.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [fraud prevention module](https://marketplace.magento.com/hexasoft-module-fraudlabspro.html) and set the validation rule to block the shipping address or the postal code.